# I need to add a value to a 2D array I created

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, matrix

So I created a 2D array with this code:

```
var grid:Array = [
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

And I have a button that (in theory) will splice a value to each row, therefore expanding the grid width-wise. The issue, however, seems not to be in my code for expanding it wider, but rather when I combine the vertical increase AND the horizontal.

Here's the current code I'm attempting to use for height increase:

```
var insertTo:int = 1;

var temp:Array = grid[0];

grid.splice(1, 0, temp);
```

And here's the current code I'm attempting to use for width increase:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < grid.length; i++){

    var insertTo:int = 1;

    grid[i].splice(insertTo, 0, 1); 

}
```

And the current unintended result after clicking the height button, then the width button (I have traces all over):

```
After height increase:
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1

After width increase:
1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
```

And here's the intended result after doing the same in reverse:

```
After width increase:
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1

After height increase:
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
```

Why does it work one way and not another, and how do I fix it?

Comment: why you dont use `push`  instead splice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must clone array befor inserting it as a new value

> The Array class has no built-in method for making copies of arrays.
>   You can create a shallow copy of an array by calling either the
>   concat() or slice() methods with no arguments. In a shallow copy, if
>   the original array has elements that are objects, only the references
>   to the objects are copied rather than the objects themselves. The copy
>   points to the same objects as the original does. Any changes made to
>   the objects are reflected in both arrays.

```
var insertTo:int = 1;

var temp:Array = grid[0].concat(); // clone

grid.splice(1, 0, temp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works 100% now. Big help.